# Confirmation email - providing a WYSIWYG so users can add HTML-ified content?

Tags: civievent, html

How do you go about having HTML in your confirmation email? I don't mean the part that you can edit under Message Templates. I mean the part that you can customized on each event's "Online Registration" tab. It shows as just a plain text box. I need to be able to add some html in that field so that there are some bolded headers in there.

I've included a screenshot of the spot that I mean.

Thanks!

EDIT: I mean a WYSIWYG editor like pretty much every other email box within CiviCRM has. Not hand coding since most people have no idea how to code HTML.

[image: Confirmation email settings]

UPDATE: Ok, so I hit another snag on this. On the event's settings page for the confirmation email, I can manually input html. That's not great since the people using it don't know HTML, which means I have to do all the changes. But now I've found a second part of the problem - that same text is copied into the field when a registration is manually entered by an admin or where they finish a registration (like taking a payment over the phone and then marking an incomplete registration as complete). However, that field can't have HTML in it. Any text there gets sent out as plain text, even though the email it is inserted to is HTML. So people see the html written out for that section instead of it being in HTML.

Comment: Updated the issue, as I found out this affects more than one area. See update in original post above.

Comment: So has anyone found out how to do this? There was work towards a patch, but from what I read, it was closed as incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

You can put basic HTML in the text box you have pictured above. **Bold**  works for email clients. The majority of email clients don't support every type of HTML content you see on the web. Web browsers are able to display scripts, animations, and complex navigation menus, while your typical email inbox isn't built to handle this type of content.

Safe to use for most email clients:
static, table-based layouts

HTML tables and nested tables

template width of 600px-800px

simple, inline CSS

web-safe fonts

Comment: The problem is the people doing those emails don't know HTML. I was hoping to have the same kind of HTML toolbar that other locations have within the software that are for emails. Like what you get inside CiviMail and are sending an email. It's odd that just about everywhere else in the software where you're sending emails you get the toolbar, but not here.

Comment: Then you should re-ask your question and add that clarity. This information totally changes the question. You said you wanted to be able to add HTML in the box. What you are now asking is if you can have a WYSIWYG editor with the box.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this PR for the patch
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13976