# Receipt for manual registration - HTML

Tags: civievent, receipts

I'd [asked about this](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21255/confirmation-email-providing-a-wysiwyg-so-users-can-add-html-ified-content) almost a year ago, and at the time was pointed towards a patch that was being worked on. But that patch, as I understand it, was closed as incomplete. Does anyone know if additional work was done on it? I really need to be able to have HTML on the confirmation email when you do a manual registration for someone or input a manual payment.

It's fine for now if it doesn't have a WYSIWYG, I just need the field to support HTML.

Right now, we have text on each individual event that gives information about the specific event, such as the location, recommended hotels, etc. It has HTML added manually to it (since that field doesn't have a WYSIWYG). That text all copies over to the receipt when you manually add a training to a record, including all the HTML tags. But when that email sends, it doesn't actually allow HTML. So all those tags just show up in the email as text.

Below is a bit of the text in the receipt that gets sent out with all the tags included. This is a screenshot from the actual email received, not the field inside Civi.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do a similar task in putting HTML in a custom token to input into an email.

Comment: Nope. Still nothing. It really frustrates our folks when they need to manually enter a payment, as they have to completely redo the receipt email since it has HTML in it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this should be possible in the manual registration.

However, you could likely work around this using CiviRules. Not knowing your exact situation I'm guessing here, but this is how I might approach it.

1. Install the 'Email API' extension (needed to be able to send email from CiviRules).
2. Install the 'CiviRules' extension.
3. Create a new participant status simply so it can be seen by the rules engine. Maybe something like 'Registered (manual)'.
4. Create a new rule 'send email to manual registrants'.
5. Make the rule trigger 'Event Participant is added'.
6. Add a linked condition to the rule 'Participant status is (not) one of'.
7. Set the condition operator to 'is one of'.
8. Choose the new participant status you created 'Registered (manual)'.
9. Add an Action 'Send Email'
10. In this example, you shouldn't need a delay, but it can be useful to introduce a short delay to allow tables to be updated if you need to test them or get data from them.
11. Lastly, set the email parameters including the message template. You can CC, BCC etc.
12. Save and test with a manual registration for a fake user. You will have to choose you the custom status you created so the rule will trigger.

You could add an additional action to the rule that changed the participant status to the normal one after the email is sent.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add more statuses like that. They use the statuses pretty heavily and have emails that go out based on them. I'd have to hunt them all down to add this new one, plus train them to remember there are now two Registered statuses. I don't see it happening and people would get left off the class lists.

Comment: There may be another condition you could use. I was just imagining your situation. You might want to install CiviRules and take a look. You may find another approach. CiviRules is pretty flexible for filling in gaps like you describe.

Comment: I already use CiviRules, but I've got to put together in such a way that it's easy for them to use and not mess with any of the processes they already know. I really wish the box would just use html since it's pulling in the receipt box, which does use html.

Comment: It is so frustrating that this problem persists in 2022. It's been discussed since at least 2014. I just spent hours on a workaround again for a series of events. If this field just supported HTML then it would have been trivial and done ages ago. Maybe time for me to see if there is any way I can do something about it myself.